# EMachines Destop won't run 13.04 or the 3.8 kernel

Tags: boot, kernel

I have an 'older' triple boot (12.10, 13.04 and Vista i386) desktop running an early version of a dual core Intel chip. It runs well on 12.10 and the 3.5 kernel, but when I upgraded the partition I use for testing and bug reports to 13.04, it will only boot either in recovery mode or on the residual 3.5 kernel.

I can't run a live dvd/usb 13.04 system or a full installation of 13.04 on an external  drive without the system rebooting before anything happens.

My newish laptop runs everything well as does my old one, which has been using Ubuntu since Hardy.

Any suggestions, both sane and wacky are requested.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your graphics card and not the kernel. Hard to know without more information. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Sure you do not have a black screen, but similar debugging procedure.